# Avoid loops for assigning event handlers in JS

Tags: javascript

I have this code, in which I'm trying to embrace JS functions like `classList` and `querySelector` but it ends up being very verbose due to loops etc for handlers:

```
var cg = document.querySelectorAll('.control-group'),
    cgL = cg.length;

while (cgL--) {
    var _cg = cg[cgL],
        inputs = _cg.querySelectorAll('input'),
        i = 0;

    for (l = inputs.length; i < l; i++) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
        inputs[i].addEventListener('blur', focus, false);
    }

    function focus() {
        _cg.classList.toggle('focus');
    }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YGeh5/3/

Is there any way to avoid having to loop around a NodeList to assign an Event Handler to each of it's elements?

Comment: you could make a function that loops for you, and then write the loop only once... e.g., `function addEventListenerToEvery(nodeList, eventsArray, func)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). But since you have a NodeList returned, and does not have `forEach()` in its prototype, you need to use `.call` and provide it as context.

However, [it's ES5. Most modern browsers have it though](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/). Also, [the polyfill is also a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility), just abstracted from you.

[Here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/YGeh5/6/), pretty much directly converted to use the `forEach()`:

```
var cg = document.querySelectorAll('.control-group');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(cg, function (group) {
  var inputs = group.querySelectorAll('input');

  function focus() {
    group.classList.toggle('focus');
  }

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
    input.addEventListener('blur', focus, false);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delegate events right on your '.control-group' and then filter inputs by e.target. It will also use consume less memory on a large amount of inputs.  Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/RZhTj/1/

```
var cg = document.querySelectorAll('.control-group'),
    cgL = cg.length;

while (cgL--) {
    var _cg = cg[cgL];

    _cg.addEventListener('focus', focus, true);
    _cg.addEventListener('blur', focus, true);

    function focus(e) {
        if (e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement) _cg.classList.toggle('focus');
    }
}
```

Comment: That's cool, I guess you could just use the nodeName property as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/RZhTj/2/

Answer (score 1):

If the browser has `Array#forEach`, you may want to use forEach for iterating over the NodeList. You first have to convert it to an array. One way to do this is to use Array.prototype.slice.

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(_cg.querySelectorAll('input'), 0).forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
});
```

Or just call Array.prototype.forEach on the NodeList:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(_cg.querySelectorAll('input'), function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
});
```

---

Note that you can group your two querySelectorAll in a single query.

You can also move the focus closure out of the loop, since it doesn't actually need a reference to the element.

And your whole code becomes:

```
function focus(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle('focus');
}

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.control-group input'), function (input) {
    input.addEventListener('focus', focus, false);
    input.addEventListener('blur', focus, false);
});
```